# Если переключиться на русский в терминале удаляются статические символы

Tags: консоль

Когда я использую английский язык, все нормально, но если я напечатаю хоть один русский символ, даже после его удалению остаются невидимые символы и появляется возможность удалить статические символы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Винда? Линукс? Мак? Какой версии? Какая версия alacritty?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Arch linux kde. alacritty 0.7.1 (a852eb85). Но это и в стандартном терминале от kde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кароче я выяснил в чем проблема. У меня не была установлена locale, я ее устанавливал при установке, но при проверке через команду `locale`, напротив всех значений у меня было С. Я в ручную прописал в файле `/ect/locale.conf` значения en_us.UTF-8 (или любая другая ваша локаль), и все стало нормально.